# How to filter bestseller collection with a product attribute

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes, best-seller

You can addAttributeToFilter for product collection;

```
$this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('att_x', ['eq', $att_x_value]);
```

How can we do this with bestseller collection (`\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory`)

And the attribute value is entity id of my custom table. I couldn't figure out how to join which tables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Method addAttributeToFilter doesn't exist in class \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection but we can use method **addFieldToFilter**

Can you retry with method addFieldToFilter?

E.g.

```
$this->_bestSellerCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('att_x', ['eq' => $att_x_value]);
```

Please note that field **att_x** needs to exist in the collection data, otherwise, we need to join it before filtering.

Comment: Hi. `att_x` doesn't exist in bestseller collection. `att_x` is a custom attribute added to product. I have to make a join to combine bestseller table, my custom table and product attributes table. I couldn't find though which tables to use for product attributes table.